# Problem updating collection using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have an entity class `Foo foo` that contains `Collection<Bar> bars`.  I've tried a variety of ways, but I'm unable to successfully update my collection.

One attempt:

```
foo = em.find(key);
foo.getBars().clear();
foo.setBars(bars);
em.flush;  \\ commit, etc.
```

This appends the new collection to the old one.

Another attempt:

```
foo = em.find(key);
bars = foo.getBars();
for (Bar bar : bars) {
    em.remove(bar);
}
em.flush;
```

At this point, I thought I could add the new collection, but I find that the entity foo has been wiped out.

Here are some annotations.
In Foo:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "foo")
private List<Bar> bars;
```

In Bar:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID")
private Foo foo;
```

Has anyone else had trouble with this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach would work if you remove `CascadeType.ALL` from `private Foo foo` and call `foo.getBars().clear()` after removing `Bar`s.

Currently, when you remove `Bar`s in your second approach, removal is propagated to the corresponding `Foo` entity, because `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

Comment: When I try that, I get:
`javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.Bar#<null>]`

Comment: @FarmBoy: You also should call `foo.getBars().clear()` after removing `Bar`s.